# Ionic angular translate not working

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

Im using ionic 2 and went through this document:

```
http://ionicframework.com/docs/resources/ng2-translate/
```

I made all the changes needed for translation to work. However, when I write this in an html file:

```
{{ 'HELLO' | translate }}
```

In the page I see

```
HELLO
```

This, even thought I have a file at /assets/i18n/en.json which contains:

```
{
    "HELLO": "Hello there"
}
```

In app.ts I added these imports:

```
import { TranslateModule, TranslateLoader } from '@ngx-translate/core';
import { TranslateHttpLoader } from '@ngx-translate/http-loader';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
```

And then after the imports I have this:

```
export function createTranslateLoader(http: Http) {
    return new TranslateHttpLoader(http, './assets/i18n/', '.json');
}
```

And also this in @NgModule->import's array:

```
TranslateModule.forRoot({
  loader: {
    provide: TranslateLoader,
    useFactory: (createTranslateLoader),
    deps: [Http]
  }
})
```

What I realized is that my app had since before this import:

```
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
```

Im not sure why I imported that but if I remove it then the app breaks in other places.
Is that the problem? Importing angular/http twice with two different names?
Tried to only use the original one, but in the export function it doesn't like the argument

```
http: HttpModule
```

insead of the one in the documentation

```
http: Http
```

Can I see if the en.json has been loaded? Or what is the problem here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can see en.json using Inspector Web (F12). Do you use these methods somewhere in your code source?

```
this.translate.setDefaultLang('en');
this.translate.use('en');
```

In the view, you see only 'HELLO' because (I think so) you did not configure the language to use.